# Files not getting copied to install directory using WIX and WAX

Tags: wix

I have some additional unmanaged dll's that need to be copied to the install folder. I am using WAX as well as it is supposed to make Wix easier to use. I have added the following markup to Product.wxs:

```
  <Component Id="DataModel1.csdl" Guid="f8fb154d-f0c9-40f5-9bcf-593ed9540bda" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
    <File Id="DataModel1.csdl" Name="DataModel1.csdl" Source="$(var.FLIR_TargetDir)DataModel1.csdl" />
  </Component>

  <Component Id="DataModel1.ssdl" Guid="a13c3c3b-e6a6-40ea-b9d8-84fd093ca0d5" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
    <File Id="DataModel1.ssdl" Name="DataModel1.ssdl" Source="$(var.FLIR_TargetDir)DataModel1.ssdl" />
  </Component>

  <Component Id="DataModel1.msl" Guid="e308d75b-1f0b-4234-843d-6b44af2e80a9" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
    <File Id="DataModel1.msl" Name="DataModel1.msl" Source="$(var.FLIR_TargetDir)" />
  </Component>

  <Component Id="Devart.Data.dll" Guid="a95a3053-7d4a-4030-b8c9-9d860a81a221" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
    <File Id="Devart.Data.dll" Name="Devart.Data.dll" Assembly=".net" KeyPath="yes"  Source="C:\Program Files (x86)\Devart\dotConnect\SQLite\Devart.Data.dll" />
  </Component>

  <Component Id="Devart.Data.SQLite.dll" Guid="16d0ca3c-425d-49e9-a754-043b0b9e4ada" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
  <File Id="Devart.Data.SQLite.dll" Name="Devart.Data.SQLite.dll" Assembly=".net" KeyPath="yes"  Source="C:\Program Files (x86)\Devart\dotConnect\SQLite\Devart.Data.SQLite.dll" />
</Component>
```

The files shows up as an unmapped file in the unmapped files area of the UI:

[image: Wax UI]

When the install happens the files do not get installed into the installation folder. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The Assembly=".NET" tell's MSI to install the files in the Global Assembly Cache. The parent directory element is ignored/overridden.  See:

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/file.html

If your looking for a tool to make WiX easier to learn/use then I'd suggest my own open source project:

https://github.com/iswix-llc/iswix-tutorials